# Filter assetset by id Webcenter Sites

Tags: webcenter, webcenter-sites

I need filter a assetset by id, my asset type is a `flex asset`. I never do this by id before and I'm stucked with this.

This is my code:

```
<publication:load name="pub" field="name" value='<%= ics.GetVar("site") %>'/>
<publication:get name="pub" field="id" output="siteId"/>

<%-- Content:getasset data is a custom tag to obtain attributes form a concrete asset --%>
<content:getassetdata prefix="lov" id='<%= ics.GetVar("assetid") %>' type="LOV" attributes="LOVUser"/>
<listobject:create name="powerObject" columns="power"/>
<c:forEach items="${lov.LOVUser}" var="usu">
    <listobject:addrow name="powerObject"><listobject:argument name="power" value="${usu.id}"/></listobject:addrow>
</c:forEach>
<listobject:tolist name="powerObject" listvarname="powerList"/>

<%-- A this time, I have a powerList with all the IDs that I need to get --%>
<searchstate:create name="ssLovElements"/>
<searchstate:addstandardconstraint name="ssLovElements" attribute="id" list="powerList" />
<assetset:setsearchedassets name="asElementLovs" constraint="ssLovElements" assettypes="elementLOV" site='<%= ics.GetVar("siteId") %>' fixedlist="false"/>
```

```
    <%-- Correct number --%>
    <br/> N.Filas powerList: <ics:listget listname="powerList" fieldname="#numRows"/>

    <%-- Incorrect number (Because constraint haven't effect --%>
    N.Filas aslist: <ics:listget listname="aslist" fieldname="#numRows"/>
```

First list have **60** elements, second list have **600**. I need use this constraint to extrac only wanted elements and get their attributes with multiplevalues, but I dont get working this. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Asset API instead of jstl tag. [See the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29634/asset_api_tutorial.htm#WBCSD2395) :

```
Session ses = SessionFactory.getSession();
AssetDataManager mgr = (AssetDataManager) ses.getManager(AssetDataManager.class.getName());
Condition c = ConditionFactory.createCondition( "id", OpTypeEnum.GREATER_THAN, long);
Query query = new SimpleQuery( "elementLOV", null, c, Arrays.asList( "name",  ) );
query.getProperties().setIsBasicSearch( true );
```